# How to create a database table from a model class?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have several model classes that have quite a few attributes to them and would like to create some tables based on these models. I have found numerous resources on how to create models based on a database, but nothing regarding creating a table from a model class. I understand that I could just create the table manually and it would work for my needs, but is there a faster way to do it?

For example, in C#, there is a package that allows me to call something like

```cs
database.CreateTable<MyClass>();
```

and it would structure a database table with all of the attributes inside of `MyClass` unless marked with an `[Ignore]` tag. The database table would be named by a tag at the top of the class like `[Table("MyClassTable")]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Isar, a NoSQL database where you annotate your model with @Collection to generate the code:

```
part 'user.g.dart';

    @collection
    class User {
      Id id = Isar.autoIncrement;
    
      String? name;
    
      int? age;
    }
```

With the command `flutter pub run build_runner build` you generate the user.g.dart file to use this model.

Check out https://pub.dev/packages/isar to read more about it.